# $C^*$- systems with positive maps

Tags: operator-theory, dynamical-systems, operator-algebras

Which is the main reason of defining a $C^*$- system as a pair of a $C^*$- algebra and a (unital) positive map $\Phi : \mathfrak{A} \rightarrow \mathfrak{A}$ ? What is the main reason behind choosing the dynamics to be a positive map on this context?

Comment: What's the context of this? I have never seen such definition, even though I have seen the name "C$^*$-System".

Comment: In general the definition of a C* system provides a $C^*$-algebra and a group homonorphism $\alpha : G \rightarrow  Aut(\mathfrak{A}) so I Guess the one I mentioned is more general.. it is related maybe to quantum information theory.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this definition?